# PyFlink - Issue with UNNEST: query uses an unsupported SQL feature?

Tags: apache-flink, pyflink

I am trying to flatten an array using UNNEST function in the Table API.

Am I doing something wrong or it is not a supported function ? This page suggests it though: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/dev/table/sql/queries.html

Thanks !

**Code**

Python udf

```
@udf(input_types=DataTypes.STRING(), result_type=DataTypes.ARRAY(DataTypes.STRING()))
def explode(s):
    return 3*[s]

t_env.register_function("explode", explode)
```

Processing

```
tab = t_env.from_path('mySource').select("id, explode(dummy) as dummy_list")
t_env.register_table("temp_table", tab)
t_env.sql_query("SELECT t.item as dummy_item FROM UNNEST(select dummy_list from temp_table) AS t(item)").insert_into("mySink")
```

Execution

```
t_env.execute("dummy_unnest")
```

**Error**

```
TableException: Cannot generate a valid execution plan for the given query: 

LogicalProject(dummy_item=[$0])
  Uncollect
    LogicalProject(EXPR$0=[org$apache$flink$table$functions$python$PythonScalarFunction$908596b4671476ee325743dba92ed6c7($1)])
      LogicalTableScan(table=[[default_catalog, default_database, mySource]])

This exception indicates that the query uses an unsupported SQL feature.
Please check the documentation for the set of currently supported SQL features.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can change the query to

```
select id, dummy_item from temp_table CROSS JOIN UNNEST(dummy_list) AS t (dummy_item)
```

Comment: :)   In the future, if you have questions with pyflink, you can also ask directly in the flink user mail list to get a more timely answer.

Comment: Thanks I will. I thought this kind of question might benefit to a wider public.